# How Can i Define A javascript Variable in My Ajax url

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

```
I want Define url Like this





  var id = $('#id').val();

    url: "category/(my difined id varibale here)/edit"
```

How can I do something like this?

I am creating project using Laravel 5.4 
here I use resource controller that why I need this kind of URL to get my controller function

```
This is the script part where I use ajax to insert data to database    

<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $(document).on('click','#edit',function(){
                   $('#modelTile').text('Edit Category');
                   $('#addItem').val($(this).data('name'));
                   $('#id').val($(this).data('id'));
                   $('#yesdelete').hide();
               });
               $('.modal-footer').on('click','#saveChange',function(){

                  var name = $('#addItem').val();
                   var id = $('#id').val();
                   var token ='{{csrf_field()}}';
                   $.ajax({
                       method : 'post',
                       url : "category/{'id'}/edit",
                   });
                   conlose.log (url);
               });

            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code to

```
$.ajax({
    method : 'post',
    url : "category/"+id+"/edit",
});
```

Comment: I am highly grateful to you. :) Thanks